# How to minimize time of execution

Tags: python, django

I have this loop:

```
start = datetime.now()
for entry in entries:
    related_entries = Related.objects.filter(entry_id=entry.entry_id, status='Related')
    lead_related_entries.append({'Entry': entry, 'related_entries': related_entries})
end = datetime.now()
print (end - start)
```

I have almost 7000+ entry with Execution time:

```
0:00:10.377000
```

Is there any tasks to do to make it faster ?

Comment: You should make your database query outside of the loop.

Comment: how can it be possible if we want the query deponds on each elt in the loop ?!!

Comment: Can you explicit what `lead_related_entries` is?

Comment: The start of an answer:  Yes, you can move the query outside the loop by using `__in` like so:  `Related.objects.filter(entry__in = entries)`, if `entry.pk == entry.entry_id`

Comment: @btoueg every entry has other related entries and `lead_related_entries` is a dictionary that combine both of them (`exemple: entry: USA, related_entries: NY, Chicago...`)

Comment: Looking at your code, `lead_related_entries` is certainly not a dictionary. Show us what it is, otherwise can't help you.

Comment: @btoueg you are right, it's a list of dictionaries: `[{'entry': USA, 'related_entries': [NY, Chicago...]}, {'entry': France, 'related_entries': [Paris, Nice...]}]`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that should make your query running faster is to use `Lazy loading`, so you only load the field you need initially.  If you need more fields later, Django will be clever enough to fetch them for you when you invoke the field.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only

Comment: I have retrieve juste 2 columns with `Related.objects.only("entry_id", "status").filter(entry_id=entry.entry_id, status='Related')` But the executed time is almost the same ! `0:00:10.940000`